# how to move transform gizmo to object center in object mode

Tags: modeling, transforms, gizmo

[image]

I want to move the transform to the center of object in object mode, not in edit mode, I have set the transform pivot point to bounding box center or any other selection, but it didn't work.

Comment: it's pretty simple, object->set origin->origin to geometry

Comment: or right click > set origin > origin to geometry